# .collect with an index

Tags: collections, groovy, iteration

Is there a `.collect` with an index? I want to do something like this:

```
def myList = [
    [position: 0, name: 'Bob'],
    [position: 0, name: 'John'],
    [position: 0, name: 'Alex'],
]

myList.collect { index ->
    it.position = index
}
```

(ie. I want to set `position` to a value which will indicate the order in the list)

Comment: it looks like it's a requested feature http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2838

Comment: answered with an actual solution below

Comment: What no love for my collect with index :)

Comment: it is pretty cool (just upvoted it), i just ended up using rob's suggestion (i don't need a collection returned). i will use your trick down the track for sure!

Comment: Updated link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2838

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Since Groovy 2.4.0 there is a [`withIndex()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#withIndex%28%29)  method which gets added to `java.lang.Iterable`.

So, in a functional fashion (no side effect, immutable), it looks like

```
def myList = [
  [position: 0, name: 'Bob'],
  [position: 0, name: 'John'],
  [position: 0, name: 'Alex'],
]

def result = myList.withIndex().collect { element, index ->
  [position: index, name: element["name"]] 
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`eachWithIndex` would probably work better:

```
myList.eachWithIndex { it, index ->
    it.position = index
}
```

Using a `collectX` doesn't really seem necessary since you're just modifying the collection and not returning particular pieces of it into a new collection.

Comment: unless you need it to return a new collection

Comment: @dstarh - Right, but the question says "I want to set the position to a value", which would make the collection seem unnecessary.

Comment: agreed, collect is probably not necessary in this case.  Were it in a chain of other calls that would be different.  I'd still however like to see a collect with index

Answer (score 13):

Slightly groovier version of collectWithIndex:

```
List.metaClass.collectWithIndex = {body->
    def i=0
    delegate.collect { body(it, i++) }
}
```

or even

```
List.metaClass.collectWithIndex = {body->
    [delegate, 0..<delegate.size()].transpose().collect(body)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do exactly what you want

```
List.metaClass.collectWithIndex = {cls ->
    def i = 0;
    def arr = [];
    delegate.each{ obj ->
        arr << cls(obj,i++)
    }
    return arr
}



def myCol = [
    [position: 0, name: 'Bob'],
    [position: 0, name: 'John'],
    [position: 0, name: 'Alex'],
]


def myCol2 = myCol.collectWithIndex{x,t -> 
    x.position = t
    return x
}

println myCol2

=> [[position:0, name:Bob], [position:1, name:John], [position:2, name:Alex]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Without adding any extension methods, you can do this in a pretty straightforward way:

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3]
def index = 0
def myOtherList = myList.collect {
  index++
}
```

It would certainly be useful for this method to exist automatically though.

Answer (score 2):

Like [dstarh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138883/dstarh) said, unless you're looking for a non-destructive method that returns a new map with your indices populated, [Rob Hruska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29995/rob-hruska)'s answer is what you're looking for.

[dstarh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138883/dstarh)'s answer provides you the non-destructive version of `collectWithIndex`, but handles the actual collection of results too.

I usually find it best to delegate such heavy lifting to the receiving object so as to play nice with polymorphic `collect` implementations, i.e., in case a specific class implements `collect` differently (than just putting the results in an array), having `collectWithIndex` delegate to it will ensure uniform behaviour. Here's how the code would look:

```
@Category(List)
class Enumerator {
    def collectWithIndex(Closure closure) {
        def index = 0
        this.collect { closure.call(it, index++) }
    }
}

use(Enumerator) {
    ['foo', 'bar', 'boo', 'baz'].collectWithIndex { e, i ->
        [index: i, element: e]
    }
}
```

Refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2043690#file_enumerate.groovy) for an example for both `eachWithIndex` and `collectWithIndex`.

Also, like the comments to your question state, there are two Jira issues open for the feature we've described- [GROOVY-2838](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2838) & [GROOVY-3797](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3797)